# How to use MinGW-W64 ld to link with ifort's dll on Windows

Tags: windows, dll, ld, intel-fortran, mingw-w64

I have a library is compiled from Intel Fortran Compilers on Windows

It has two file `foo.dll` and `foo.lib`

Because the function name decoration of windows's ifort is different with gfortran or linux's ifort, when I directly link with `foo.lib` (-lfoo) it will cause `undefined reference to 'bar_'`.

I use `pexports` to generate def file and edit like that

```
LIBRARY foo.dll
EXPORTS
bar_ = bar
...
```

and use `dlltool -d foo.def -l foo.a` to make a .a file

I can link to foo.a successfully, but when the program run, it throw

`The specified procedure could not be found.`

`Entry Point Not Found`

How can I directly link `bar_` function in source object to `bar` function in dll?

I don't want to write a warp.

P.S.

I also had try to static link to original linux's .a on Mingw-w64 on Windows, the ld show `could not read symbols: Invalid operation`.